# Using xp_cmdshell to execute .bat succeed, but does nothing

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-2014, xp-cmdshell

**I'm using MS SQL server 2014 web edition.**

I created a maintenance plan, and I used a T-SQL statement task to execute xp_cmdshell to execute a batch file.

T-SQL statement:

```
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'Path\XX.bat'
```

When doing so, I get success. But the batch file isn't working.
(*it should compress the .bak files using winrar*). The batch file works fine when executed manually. The login I'm using is "sa" has sysadmin role, and the owner of the master database.

I checked if I can reach the path and turns out I can cause I can see the files in there, using this:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir X\XXX'
```

Comment: Add `echo test > test.txt` to your .bat to verify that it's firing.  Check that you can reach the location of the .bak files from `xp_cmdshell` too.

Comment: Check priviliges for SQL Server service account.

Comment: Redirect output from the batch file to a file: `exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'Path\XX.bat > Path\outp.txt'` and see what that tells you.